# if ( ! function_exists

Tags: php

I have added `if ( ! function_exists ( 'event_meta_box' ) ) {` to my child theme functions.php along with the existing function and my changes.

When loading the site I get the following error
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare event_meta_box() (previously declared in /home/user/public_html/folder/wp-content/themes/theme-child/functions.php:10) in /home/user/public_html/folder/wp-content/themes/theme/include/functions-new.php on line 3920

How is this fixed?

Comment: this is just a comment on why you get the error, not a solution: functions.php of your child theme gets loaded first, and the /include/functions-new.php of your theme gets loaded sometime after. therefore your function `event_meta_box` gets defined first, and when your theme tries to define that same function (again) it triggers the error. To have this work, your parent theme would need to have the `! function_exits` code https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

Comment: The code originally comes from the Parent theme. I added it to the child functions.php then this error says. The error makes it look like the other way for some reason

Comment: what theme are you using, and have you contacted the theme's developers for help?

Answer (score 1):

The child theme **functions.php** is actually loaded *first* (this is intentional and desired behaviour.) So despite the `function_exists` check in your child theme, it will achieve nothing, as it seems the parent theme does *not* have this wrapper and is loaded second, so a fatal error occurs.

There is no easy way to override a parent theme function (if it hasn't made all of it's functions pluggable by default - mine does but few do!) Sometimes the parent theme function is hooked to an action, and you can remove the function from the hook (using `remove_action`) and then then add your own custom function (using `add_action`). Other times (even more rarely) there is a filter available in the existing theme code.

Other that that you will have to get more creative by copying the relevant parent theme template(s) to your child theme and modifying it/them to change the function called to your custom one, or hook that is fired - as child theme templates are used *instead* of parent theme ones. But remember, both child and parent **functions.php** are loaded.